# Strict Henselization vs base-change to algebraic closure

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra

Let $x$ be a smooth $k$-point on a variety $X$ over a field $k$ of characteristic $0$.

Is the strict Henselized local ring $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}^{\mathrm{sh}}$ the same as $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}^{\mathrm{h}} \otimes_k \overline{k}$, where $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}^{\mathrm{h}}$ denotes the Henselized local ring?

Comment: Is $x$ a closed point?

Comment: Take $X=Spec(K)$ with $K$ a non-trivial Galois extension of $k$, and $x=X$. The strict henselization is the field $\bar{k}$ while, by elementary Galois theory, the tensor product $K\otimes_k\bar{k}$ is a non-trivial finite product.

Comment: By Hensel lemma won't $\hat{O}_P=\varprojlim \Bbb{Q}[t]_{(t^2+1)}/(t^2+1)^n$ contain a root $I$ of $T^2+1$, won't its strict henzelization be $\hat{O}_P\otimes_{\Bbb{Q}(I)} \overline{\Bbb{Q}}$ ?

Comment: Is there a counterexample where $x$ is a $k$-point of $X$?

Comment: @Deni and : Sorry, I forgot to include the condition that $x$ is a $k$-point. The question should make more sense now.

Comment: I think that this is equivalent to the question whether the Nisnevich neighbourhoods of $(X_{\bar k}, \bar x)$ that are defined over $k$ are cofinal among all Nisnevich neighbourhoods. I don't immediately see whether this should be true, but my guess is no already for $\mathbf A^1_{\mathbf R}$, as there are many étale covers without $\mathbf R$-points.

Comment: For $k$-points, this works: if $A$ a henselian ring, there is an equivalence of categories between finite separable extensions of the residue field and the category of étale $A$-algebras of finite presentation $B$ such that $Spec(B)$ is connected and surjects to a neighborhood of the residue field. Such $B$ is then in fact finite over $A$. If $A$ is a $k$-algebra and if its residue field is equal to $k$, this means that any connected étale neighborhood of the closed point is canonically the pullback of $Spec(k)$ along a finite separable extension.

Comment: Writing the strict henselization as a filtered colimit of $B$'s where $B$ run over all rings of functions on connected étale neighborhood of the closed point gives the expected isomorphism.

Comment: @Remy: They can be defined over $\mathbb{R}$ but not have $\mathbb{R}$-points!

I know of a statement like that for finite \'{e}tale covers.

Comment: Right; by @Denis-CharlesCisinski's comment I was thinking about it the wrong way. I meant defined over $\mathbf R$ as Nisnevich neighbourhood, which requires an $\mathbf R$-point above the origin.